# Vertical Aligning input type="button"

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of trouble with the vertical aligning input `type="button"`.

HTML

```
<input name="" type="button" class="question-button-1 btn-1" value="Call us" />
```

CSS

```
.btn-1 {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/KSR0hpJ.png) top left no-repeat;
  width: 313px;
  height: 78px;
  font-family: 'pt_sansbold';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLcNd/3/

I used `vertical-align: top;` but it looks like it absolutely doesn't work.
How to move the text to the top edge of a button? (I need to use `input type="button"`)

Comment: Add `padding-bottom: 45px;`

Comment: @mdesdev - post as an answer no?

Comment: Yes an answer in comment ;)

Comment: @mdesdev But that is not the complete answer. For instance if you add `padding-bottom:45px;` at the beginning of the style block, it won't have an effect.

Comment: @MrLister yes, but why would he keep `padding: 0;` and add `padding-bottom: 45px;` I didn't post this as an answer and I didn't want to elaborate that, but never mind he can use `padding: 0 0 45px 0;`

Comment: It's not a problem, I definitely understand I should set `padding-bottom: 45px;` after `padding: 0;` or use `padding: 0 0 45px 0;`